# If a SSD fails, using z68 caching, data on HDD is lost?

Tags: ssd, cache

If my SSD fails, the HDD data will be lost? Does it works like RAID 0, when data is stripped between the two drives? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the SRT mode. In 'maximized' mode, an SSD failure will make the drive unusable. In 'enhanced' mode, an SSD failure will just result in SRT being disabled. Essentially, 'maximized' mode is a write-back cache with writes waiting only for the SSD to complete. In 'enhanced' mode, writes must hit the hard drive to be considered complete, essentially a write-through cache. Performance will drop in enhanced mode compared to maximized mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that your SSD is failing and still have access to Windows. I would disable the SSD. Who makes your SSD? If it's Intel then google for the Intel Toolbox or Intel Toolkit. It will show you the health of the SSD and the estimated life remaining.

To answer your question directly, it depends. When setting up the SSD, did you enable Enhanced or Maximized. If you enabled Enhanced then you should be okay to pull the SSD if fails. If Maximized then you're probably screwed if you are unable to boot. I would suggest that you immediately disable acceleration and put it in Enhanced if you must continue to use the SSD SRT.

Right Click and View Image for Larger Size
[image]